# for loop , loops one more time than it have to

Tags: c++, for-loop, codeblocks

I'm working on a simple short C++ code and the for loop is looping one more than it have to (developed using code::blocks):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    for (x=10; x<20; x++);
    cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

The out put is 20 but as far as I know it has to be 19.

link for image : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WsVzm6FTagbC1uNHpMZ1p6SW8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x < 20` is the condition that must be met in order to stay inside the loop, which means that you'll only exit the loop when `x >= 20`, so when you reach `x = 19` you'll still iterate one more time because `19 < 20`.

Comment: so it loops 10 times but iterates 11 times?

Comment: the **for** instruction will iterate 10 times (execute x++), but the condition **x < 20** will be evaluated 11 times. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

The output is correct. The second statement `x<20` defines whether or not the loop will be executed. However, x gets increased to 20, the condition is not met and the loop is not executed. Your code prints the x variable after the for-loop that's why 20 is the correct ouput.

Answer (score 1):

The middle part in the foor loop ;x<20; is the loop condition.
Meaning it won't execute the x++ again if it is not true any more. Thus the loop will stop only when x reaches 20

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite your code using a while loop, that may make it more clear:

```
int main() {
    int x = 10;
    while (x < 20)
        x++;
    cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When written this way, it is clear that at the iteration when the while loop ends that `x == 20`.